# How to auto size text in a TextRange in PowerPoint

Tags: .net, c++-cli, powerpoint, office-interop

I am creating a PowerPoint using C++/CLI and the .net framework. I will not know how much text will be in a text box/TextFrame. I was wondering if there is a way to auto size the text inside the text box/TextFrame so the text will fit into the size of text box I have created. The width does not change, but the height is changing on me.

I know you can set the font size by doing

```
TextRange->Font-> Size = 12
```

But is there a way to do something like

```
TextRange->Font-> AutoSize = true;
```

or

```
TextRange->TextExceedBoundaried = False;
```

Or something to that effect?

As of right now I input the text and then the text box changes size and shape. How can I get the text to change size depending on the size of the text box, not the text box change depending on the size of the text.

Answer (score 1):

In VBA, assuming a reference to the shape in oSh:

```
With oSh.TextFrame2
    .AutoSize = msoAutoSizeTextToFitShape
End With
```

[and added as an afterthought]

msoAutoSizeTextToFitShape is a constant, VB/VBA Long = 2

That'd be an Integer in .NET, I believe.

Comment: This works, and it's important to use the TextFrame2 since the original TextFrame property doesn't give you the option of sizing the text to fit the shape. Thanks! Can't believe this question, and correct answer, had zero upvotes.